# Django - Email sending twice

Tags: python, django, email

Whenever I call the method below from views.py with the email settings shown below, two copies of the email are sent to the recipient and I get the error shown below:

```
def sendEmailBasic(request):
   msg = EmailMessage('Request Callback',
                      'Here is the message.', to=['example@gmail.com'])
    msg.send() 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 58207)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
self.finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
self.wfile.close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
self.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
```

Comment: Which version of django?

The error seems like your browser has disconnected from your django development server.

Put some logs/prints inside your view function to check how much time `msg.send()` takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers will often send a HEAD request to any URL they can find.  If Django operates on the HEAD request, then again on the following GET request, you'll see functions being called twice.

Consider moving the "send mail" function to a POST request, or only send email on a real GET, not anything else.

Untested:

```
def sendEmailBasic(request):
   if request.method in ('GET', 'POST'):
       msg = EmailMessage('Request Callback',
                      'Here is the message.', to=['example@gmail.com'])
       msg.send() 
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

See also: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/