# Django Email sent twice

Tags: python, django, email

I have an odd problem.....I was fiddling with django's email backend...tested both console and smtp backend.....the email is sent twice! I can't trace why its happenning....

here's the view that calls the email sending operation:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage

def index(request):
    if request.method in ('GET'):
        print request.method
        mail = EmailMessage(subject='Subject Here', body='Here be the msg!', from_email='admin@test.com', to=['recipient@email.com'])
        mail.send()
        #send_mail(subject='Subject Here', message='Here be the msg!', from_email='admin@test.com', recipient_list=['recipient@email.com'])

    return HttpResponse('Mail Sent')
```

As can be seen, I used both EmailMessage class with send() method and also the send_mail() function.....but both behaves the same.....and the email is sent twice!!

Any help?

Comment: Is the `print` statement also running twice?

Comment: one more, in `to` parameter `to=['recipient@email.com']` email ID can not be duplicate.

Comment: Just a hint...you probably want to use POST instead of GET to avoid abuse.

Comment: make sure your `from_email` and `to` are not same

Comment: @mevius: Yes the print statement is running twice....

Comment: @VivekSable: there is only one recipient....no duplicates....tested by changing the recipient too.....

Comment: @JOSEFtw: Yap i know....i was just testing it.....if fact the 1st sample of the code was not checking for any request at all....thus i thought there were more than one request type calling the view twice....but its GET both time....

Comment: yes,, can ypu upload code or recheck how url of this view function is called?

Comment: @AbhiP: Nope not same.....the from_email is the same as seen here....i used my personal gmail as the EMAIL_HOST_USER in settings.py to send the mails.....and changed from_email string to various cases for testing...

Comment: @VivekSable: checked my code again.....yes there was a problem in the code structure...I did not create any app by startapp command....instead used the default created during startproject command, which creates a package the same name as the folder....
Thanx all for pointing in the right direction....:)....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522928/django-email-sending-twice

Comment: If the print statement is running twice, it means the function is called twice and hence the mail is sent twice. The best way to send email is through POST request. This will make sure POST is done only once. Browser can do multiple GET request and it is hard to control. So try POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and spent hours looking for a solution, which I think I found with help [from this link](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/). I think my web browser may be the root cause of this problem.
I have an ajax call to the Django view followed by a window.redirect

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'add_to_cart' %}",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        ajax: 'yes',
        ids: JSON.stringify(IDs),
        xxxx: $("#xxxx").val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    if (response == "OK") {
        $('#cart_name').val('');
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
});
```

I just delete `window.location.href = '/';` 
This prevent the brower to send twice the ajax call. I don't have much time to investigate why a simple `window.location.href = '/';` make a second unwanted call.